# MaatWebsite Excel, outputting only last column, if I get first row

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I can't seem to get the full header row, when using MaatWebsite Excel with Laravel.

My file is as follows...

```
Row 1 data  |  Test11  | Test1
Row 2 data  |  Test22 | Test2
Row 3 data  |  Test33 | Test3
```

If I do this...

```
$tempFile = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load(storage_path().$tempFile, function($reader){
     $reader->setHeaderRow(1);
     $results = $reader->get()->toArray();
});
```

$results becomes...

```
    Row 2 data  |  Test22 | Test2
    Row 3 data  |  Test33 | Test3
```

If I do this `setHeaderRow(0)` though...you would think Id get the same thing, but including the first row.  But I dont.

```
$tempFile = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load(storage_path().$tempFile, function($reader){
     $reader->setHeaderRow(0);
     $results = $reader->get()->toArray();
});
```

$results becomes...

```
    Test1
    Test2
    Test3
```

So the problem is if I start reading on the second row, I get all the data from all columns, EXCEPT the first row.

But if I start reading on the first row, I get all the rows, but only get the last column.

What's going on here?

Comment: Check this thread: [How to add header row in export excel file with maatwebsite in Laravel](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-add-header-row-in-export-excel-file-with-maatwebsite-in-laravel-58example.html)

Comment: Im not trying to add a header.  Im trying to read the first row from an already existing file

Comment: try this once:- `$reader = Excel::load(storage_path() . <file path with file name>)->get();
$headerRow = $reader->first()->keys()->toArray();`

Comment: The problem has been updated.  I wasnt really clear the first time. The issue is when I read from the first row, I dont get the entire rows anymore.  I only get the last column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by simply adding...

```
config(['excel.import.heading'=>false]);
```

before all my Excel:: code.